# reading strings from large file faster

Tags: python, string, file, file-io

I have a large text file (`parsed.txt`) which includes almost 1.500.000 lines. Each line is in this format:

```
foobar foo[Noun]+lAr[A3pl]+[Pnon]+[Nom]
loremipsum lorem[A1sg]+lAr[A3pl]+[Pl]+[Nom]
```

I'm giving the second field after space and get the first field before space with this function:

```
def find_postag(word,postag):
    with open('parsed.txt',"r") as zemberek:    
        for line in zemberek:
            if all(i in line for i in (word,postag)):
                if line.split(" ")[0].startswith(word) and line.split(" ")[1] == word+postag:
                    selectedword = line.split(" ")[0]
                    break
        return selectedword
```

However, it works too slow. I'm not sure how can I make the process faster. My idea is: The `parsed.txt` file is alphabetic ordered. If given `word` variable starts with "z" letter, it reads almost 900.000 lines unnecessarily. Maybe it will be faster if it will check from line 900.000 if the given `word` starts with "z" letter. Is there any better ideas and how can I implement?

Comment: Consider reading and parsing the file just once. Store it's contents in a dictionary for fast lookups. The rest of the data can be parsed into something more friendly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input file is alphabetical, what you could do is create a dictionary that contains the line number where each letter starts, like this:

```
with open('parsed.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]

index = dict()
for i in range(len(data)):
    line = data[i]
    first_letter = line[0].lower()
    if first_letter not in index:
        index[first_letter] = i
```

You would want to add that code at the beginning so it only runs once before you start doing the searches. This way when you search for a word, you can have it start searching where its first letter starts, like this:

```
def find_postag(word, postag):
    start = index[word[0].lower()]
    for line in data[start:]:
        # your code here
        if all(i in line for i in (word,postag)):
            if line.split(" ")[0].startswith(word) and line.split(" ")[1] == word+postag:
                selectedword = line.split(" ")[0]
                break
    return selectedword
```